# Using an abstract class in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class, number-formatting

*Java* Documentation says `NumberFormat` is an abstract class. But the following line of code is confusing me.

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

How can we use this `NumberFormat.getInstance()` when `NumberFormat` is an abstract class?
Can anyone help me in understanding this please?

Comment: `NumberFormat.getInstance` is a static method. Abstract classes can have static method. Apparently, this one returns a subclass of `NumberFormat` (`NumberFormatImpl`, perhaps?)

Answer (score 6):

[`NumberFormat.getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getInstance%28%29) is a [*static factory method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which can return an instance of a concrete subclass of the abstract `NumberFormat` class:

It's something like this:

```
abstract class Instrument {
    public static Instrument getInstance() {
        return new Guitar();
    }
}

class Guitar extends Instrument { }
```

So, when you call:

```
Instrument.getInstance();
```

You would get an instance of `Guitar`, which is a concrete subclass.

Answer (score 2):

The `getInstance()` method returns a subclass of NumberFormat - the default for your locale.

Answer (score 2):

You can *call* `NumberFormat.getInstance()` because it's a static method. You don't need an instance of a class to call a static method on that class.

`NumberFormat.getInstance()` can declare a return type of `NumberFormat` because it will *actually* return an instance of a concrete subclass - but that's compatible with `NumberFormat` in the same way that this works:

```
String x = "test";
Object y = x;
```

If you print out `NumberFormat.getInstance().getClass()` you'll see which *actual* concrete subclass is being used - but you shouldn't depend on it returning any particular class; the point is that you're just meant to use methods specified on `NumberFormat` itself.

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat.getInstance()` returns non-abstract `DecimalFormat` implementation by default.